# Moving a platform in 2d space left and right continuosly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move a cube left and right in a restricted space constantly on x-axis. But the cube keeps on moving only in one direction as in keep moving left till it is out of the screen. The position for the starting x-axis is 0. Wrote the following code in C# for Unity3d. Thanks for any advice.

```
void Update () {

        if (transform.position.x < 1)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 0.1f);
        }
        else if (transform.position.x > -1)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 0.1f);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here. First, as the other answer pointed out, you seem to have your less-than & greater-than symbols swapped, so you're always going into the first (left) block.

Second, you're always basing which direction to move on the current location, which sounds right, but actually isn't. What you really want is to go "the current direction", whatever that is, unless you're at the edge, in which case "the current direction" needs to be reversed.

That is, you need something like this:

```
private Vector3 movement = Vector3.left * 0.1f;

public void Update() {
    if (cube.position.x > 1)
        movement = Vector3.left * 0.1f;
    else if (cube.position.x < -1)
        movement = Vector3.right * 0.1f;

    transform.Translate(movement);
}
```

Edit: Thanks to Chris Hayes for pointing out that Vector3 isn't nullable. I'm not familiar with Unity3d, just with this general problem.

Edit2: To further clarify, you can't just have 2 zones, and say, "If it's in this zone, move left, and if it's in the other zone, move right." Then it just ends up oscillating back & forth on the border between the two zones. What you need is three zones:

```
<-- (move right) -->|<-- (keep going same direction) -->|<-- (move left) -->
```

Comment: If I recall it's actually not nullable, but of course you can use a bool or some other variable to track it. Or just initialize the Vector3 in the constructor.

Comment: I tried out the above codes and the cube doesn't move at all.

Comment: @keshk I'm not familiar with Unity3d. Does moving left involve *increasing* the X coordinate or *decreasing* the X coordinate? That is, if X is 2, is the cube off the screen to the left or the right?

Comment: I changed your code at else if to - (transform.position.x < 1). This way the cube works to move right till it hits 1. Following that it tries to go left but after a single step, it ends up in a battle between the 2 if statements cos the single step just made the other if statement activate again. hope I am clear. :)

Comment: position.x is just defining the axis. There is no value there. Vector3.right is what makes the cube go right. I multiply it by 0.1f to manage the speed at which it moves right.

Comment: @keshk What do you mean by "defining the axis"? Is transform the cube's position, a set of X-Y-Z coordinates?  Can you give me the X-Y-Z coordinates for the top left corner of the screen and the bottom right corner of the screen?

Comment: The cube is at x,y,z - 0,0,0. Top left corner of screen: -7,7,0. Bottom right corner: 7.5,-1,0

Comment: @keshk And `transform` is the cube's position?

Comment: Every object(int this case, the cube) has *transform* to be used to change position rotation or scale.                                   eg. transform.position.x = vector3.right moves the cube right on x-axis.

Comment: @keshk Oh, then you don't want transform in the if statement. You want to base the movement on cube's position. See edit.

Comment: I get the logic you have put together but unable to visualize a set of codes for it. Putting Unity aside, able to just help show in C# how you would place the if statements? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

all values .99 to -.99 are less than 1 so your else is never hit. unless your value is greater than 1